# JavaScript Combination Inheritance Pattern

Tags: javascript, inheritance

In the chapter of [Professional JavaScript for Web Developers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118026691) on OOP, Nicholas Zachas describes a JavaScript inheritance pattern which he refers to as *combination inheritance*. The basic idea is that methods are inherited via prototype chaining; whereas parent properties are passed on to descendants by calling the parent constructor within the child constructor.

A small example:

```
function Parent() {
    this.parentProperty;
}

Parent.prototype.parentMethod = function() {
    console.info(parentProperty);
}

function Child() {
    Parent();
}

Child.prototype = new Parent();
```

He concludes his discussion by saying that "combination inheritance is the most frequently used inheritance pattern in JavaScript."

However, in his following discussion on the prototypal inheritance pattern, he mentions a shortcoming of combination inheritance, namely that the child type invokes the parent constructor twice: once when creating the prototype and then again in the constructor.

My question is why does the combination inheritance pattern suggest extending the prototype by having the child's prototype be an **instance** of the parent type, why shouldn't it just reference the parent's prototype directly? Using the previous example, why not just do the following:

```
Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;
```

Comment: You want this `Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)`.

Comment: @elclanrs: not really; that wouldn't give the child the parent's state; besides that's an example of prototypal inheritance.

Comment: You don't want to set a reference to the parent prototype, because both prototypes would be the same object. What if you want to add properties only to the child prototype? With Object.create you make a prototypical clone, in other words, a new object with its prototype set to the parent's prototype. This is a common idiom, and it is similar to assigning an instance but without calling the constructor function.

Comment: Ah, I see. Indeed, your alternative is obviously more correct than mine, and it's good to know that it's a "common idiom". Turn your comments into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @elclanrs, can you post your comment as an answer please? :)

Answer (score 1):

By doing:

```
Child.prototype = Parent.prototype;
```

You are essentially creating a reference to `Parent`'s prototype, which means any property added to `Child`'s prototype is now added to `Parent`'s prototype as well.

On the other hand by doing:

```
Child.prototype = new Parent();
```

`Child`'s prototype inherits all the properties of `Parent` via prototype chaining, thus adding a property to `Child`'s prototype doesn't affect the `Parent`'s prototype.

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
```

The above achieves same thing except it doesn't run the `Parent`'s [constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17952160) function when creating `Child`'s prototype.